# How to get subscription and unsubscribe URL

Tags: magento2.3, newsletter-subscriber, subscription

I am trying to send Subscribe & unsubscribe URL to customer on new order or other alerts via email.

I have tried below code, but it does not work. I am currently using Magento **2.3.5-p1** version, can anyone please suggest me URL or code that's going to work?

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getSubscriptionLink()}}">Subscribe</a> 
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">Unsubscribe</a>
```

I also tried `subscriber_data.subscrption_link` but it does not work.

Comment: i think this will work for unscription <a href=”{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}”>
{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
</a>

Comment: doesn't work, i have posted this URL in my question.